# PHP5 writing the actual array to file

Tags: php, arrays, file

Have a file that is included in all pages, content below

```
    <?php

        site['subTitle'] = "Welcome to the Site";
    ?>
```

On one page I am trying to change the "Welcome to the Site" to "Whatever" via a form text field and then save the included file so I will get:

```
    <?php
        site['subtitle'] = "Whatever";
    ?>
```

Currently am unable to work out how to write this out, anyone know how to do this. Have tried json and file_put_contents($filename, print_r($site, true)), but the resulting output doesn't match my requirement.

Comment: `site['subTitle']` that isn't your *real* code, right? `site` is currently being treated as a constant.

Comment: Are you designing a CMS? If you have to ask a question like this, it seems like you should just install one that's already designed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
$contents = "<?php\n\n\$site = array();\n";

foreach ($strings as $key => $value) {
    $contents.= '$site[\''.$key.'\'] = \''.$value.'\';'."\n";
}

file_put_contents($path_to_file, $contents);
```

You would of course escape both $key and $value in real life application.